# After login users must accept new conditions

Tags: login, terms-of-service

I am wondering which action should I use when customer change terms of usage and conditions.

Flow is:

1. User login
2. New conditions appear
3. User to get access to portal must accept conditions
4. If user doesn't accept

   a) should has delete account option?

   b) should has option "I do not accept" and contact ?

What do you think which option is better ?

Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would refrain from displaying destructive (Delete) option on this screen. I'd go with something more informative, like 'Tell me more'. Once user reaches that page, they might be able to delete their account. The key here is to make sure user makes informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what the account is for. Is it for an online shop ? Might the user have waranty certificates inside his account or things that he might need later even if he does not agree with your new terms ?

You could limit the users access through the app unless he agrees with the new terms, but he should still be able to see what he has inside the app.

I do not accept and Contact would make no sense.

Delete option would be ok but considering what I said above about data that the user shouldn`t lose in one click.